# How to share files on all computers back and forth with my isp and second router connected?

Tags: router, file-sharing, ipv4, adsl-router, bridging

[image]

I have 7 computers, but I can only share files with computers in router-1 (ISP router), but in the second router, I can't see anything behind it on the network. I have PLDTMyDSL router in philippines, and a EDIMAX BR-6214K

---

**Update 1**

this is my Internet Router
[image]

and my 2nd router
[image]

I get internet connection from first router using the blue cable. I want to share files between devices connected to both routers. any idea how to do this?

---

**Update 2**

My ADSL Router web-UI
[image]

[image]

Comment: The text is too short and unclear. Please add more details.

Comment: Try to set up VPN between your routers (if they can do it and are enough compatible to understand each other). It will connect your separate networks into one network.

Comment: added updated, by the way how to setup VPN? does it need to be paid, right?

Comment: *how to setup VPN?* Read user manual for your device, nobody will do it except you... primarily look for VPN abbreviate. *does it need to be paid* No until additional payment for a VPN connection is written in ISP agreement explicitly.

Comment: Set on both of your networks [tinc](https://www.tinc-vpn.org/) and you will get what you want

Answer (score 1):

You can't see the second router from the first or the computers because of the second routers NAT/firewall.

Connect the ISP router to the second router via lan port to lan port.

Note: these instructions are assuming router-1 lan address is at 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0, with DHCP being served from this router. If it isn't the default, replace these IP numbers with the scheme in use. (Make sure router-1 & router-2 are in the same network space)

Disable DHCP on the second router, put it's lan ip address outside of the first routers DHCP range. 192.168.1.254 255.255.255.0 usually works, but you should make sure the first routers DHCP doesn't overlap .254

Disable the firewall on the second router if you have the option.

Once this is done, you should renew the DHCP leases on all lan computers/devices. Make sure that they are receiving leases from the first router.

You should now be good to go with file sharing across all devices.